# Chrome extension to save the content in a form

Tags: windows, gratis, chrome, forms

I'm looking for an extension for chrome where if I'm filling out a form, it will be able to save everything I have filled out in all the feilds. The reason for this is sometimes I'm filling out contact forms, applications, etc. and I don't have all the needed information needed to complete the form. Some of these forms are quite lengthy so simply retyping in information again would become time-consuming. I then have to leave my browser and its tab open until I've found all the necessary information to complete the form. Having an extension like this where I could save what I have currently written would enable me to close the tab & browser if I wanted.

I would like the extension to meet these requirements:

- Gratis
- Compatible with Windows 10
- Has a save form field feature
- Has a restore form field feature (I can restore the content in the fields from a previous save)

Comment: On Firefox I've used *Lazarus* in the past, which is [also available for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/lazarus%20form%20recovery?itemlang&hl=en&q=lazarus) so you might wish to take a look at it.